# Java - Running a program without starting with initial code for output

Tags: java

I am writing code for a competition which uses an automatic grader, and the competition requires for no extra code (outputs saying stuff like "Please input abc"). When testing the code, I started the program with:

```
System.out.println();
```

This would create an initial output so I could then input stuff. If I were to remove it, the program wouldn't run. However, I want the program to run with no System.out.println in the beginning.

i.e:

```
public class Program{
    public static void main(String [ ] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in){
        String a = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

If I just do this, and only print an output at the very end of all the inputs, it will not run. How do I make it run without a System.out.println before the input?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

For the program to run you don't need to print out anything. The main method will execute first. However I don't see you "importing" the Scanner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String a = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Also in Java you usually name your classes with an uppercase letter, like "Program", although this is not essential for the program to run.

Comment: Hey: I only used my thing as an example, my actual program is several hundred lines long and I do have a scanner imported. When my program is executing, I just want a window to appear where I can input a string. This doesn't happen with my current program (sc.nextLine() before my only output)

Comment: The problem isn't the program itself, I just want a screen where I can enter inputs to pop up when I run it. If I don't include System.out.println() before the statement, the window won't pop up and I don't have anywhere to put inputs. I want to achieve this input screen to come up without the System.out.println() before the entire code.